# own bibliography style with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

My bibliography has to look like this:

> name, givenname; name2 ,givenname2: title. edition location : publisher, Year.

e.g.

> Weck, Manfred; Brecher, Christian: Werkzeugmaschinen. 6.Auflage Berlin
>   : Springer, 2005.

my `bib`-file looks like this:

```
@BOOK{weck,
  title = {Werkzeugmaschinen},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {2005},
  author = {Manfred Weck and Christian Brecher},
  address = {Berlin},
  edition = {6.Auflage}
}
```

my `tex` file like this:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=alphabetic,  sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{\addcolon}
  \newunit\newblock \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\adddot}
  \newunit\newblock \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit \printlist{location} %
  \setunit{\addcolon}
  \newunit \printlist{publisher}
  \setunit{\addcomma}
  \newunit \printfield{year}
  \finentry}
```

but my bibliography looks like this

> Manfred Weck and Christian Brecher. Werkzeugmaschinen. 6.Auflage
>   Berlin. Springer. 2005

So the name has to come first and if there are more than one author there has to be a `;` in between. semicolons and colons seem to be ignored, there's always a dot.

Comment: Which (bib/cite) style do you use? And why exactly don't you use one of the existing bibliography drivers for `book`?

Comment: added style and my professor gave me this format which i have to use.

Comment: Just to be sure: Does your professor want that the content of any other `.bib` field besides title/publisher/year/author/address/edition is ignored? And that there is no space between "6." and "Auflage"?

Comment: only those fields are mandatory. the field edition is "6.Auflage" so i just have to insert a space between if necessary

Comment: Is it mandatory to delete other fields? (I'm working on an answer as we speak.)

Comment: what do you with that. its my decision which fields i use. i write the bib file by my own, so i would just leave the optional fields blank

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example that doesn't create a new bibliography driver from scratch, but modifies the existing `book` driver. Try and comment out my redfinitions to see what they effect. Note that I have changed the contents of the `edition` field in your `.bib` file to an integer and instead used the `babel` package plus the `biblatex` package option `abbreviate=false`.

Note: In the bibliography driver in your code snippets, semicolons and colons aren't ignored, but overridden by the following `\newunit` which typesets `\newunitpunct` (by default, a period and a space)  instead.

Further information may be found at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\renewbibmacro*{author/editor+others/translator+others}{%
  \mkbibbold{% ADDED
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{author}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test \ifuseeditor
       and
       not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
     }
       {\usebibmacro{editor+others}}
       {\usebibmacro{translator+others}}}}
  }% ADDED

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
%    {\setunit*{addcolon\space}}% DELETED
    {\setunit*{~:\space}}% ADDED
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
%    {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}% DELETED
    {\mkbibordedition{#1}\bibstring{edition}}% ADDED
    {#1\isdot}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{weck,
  author = {Manfred Weck and Christian Brecher},
  year = {2005},
  title = {Werkzeugmaschinen},
  edition = {6},
  location = {Berlin},
  publisher = {Springer},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works perfectly would be nice if the authors are bold and the title is cursive

Comment: @Andy See edited answer.