# Elsevier style citation for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm writing thesis and I'm forced to use citation format same as used Elsevier/ScienceDirect journals:

> [#] Authors: Title, Editors: Booktitle, Publisher,
>   volume(number)(year), pages.

ie.:

> [`1`] P.K. Chu and L. Li:
>   Characterisation of..., *Materials CHemistry and Physics*,
>   96(2-3)(2006), 253-277.

There are `.bst` style files for BibTeX, but I'm using `biblatex`. The one from all Elsevier's `.bst` files is [elsart-num](http://www.elsevier.com/framework_authors/misc/elsart-num.bst), others are available [there](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsart).

- Is there any `biblatex` style providing same citation style?
- Is there *easy* way to create such that one or tune existing `biblatex` style?
- Is it possible to create command/macro providing output: "From {AUTHOR}:{Title}[{reference}]." using BibTeX? (in `biblatex` I'm using
  `\newcommand\foo[1]{\Citeauthor{#1}: \citetitle{#1} \cite{#1}.}`)

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45757/own-bibliography-style-with-biblatex

Comment: I voted to close this question. It's always the best to provide a first minimal example and a question should only consist of one question.

Comment: At the very least, you should provide a link to the exact `.bst` file you want to have emulated.

Comment: Elsevier is providing you with a template latex document and accompanying bibtex file. You shouldn't use biblatex just because you prefer that over bibtex - just like you shouldn't use LibreOffice Writer instead of Latex. The template is there for a reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be what you want. Traditional `elsart-num`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
@book{Kop04,
  author = {Kopka, Helmut and Daly, Patrick W.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Guide to \LaTeX},
  edition = {4},
  address = {Boston},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{elsart-num}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`biblatex` emulation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[firstinits=true,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
  }{%
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
  }%
}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
@book{Kop04,
  author = {Kopka, Helmut and Daly, Patrick W.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Guide to \LaTeX},
  edition = {4},
  location = {Boston},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

For further information see [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).

Comment: I suppose the file "elsar-num.bst" mentioned in the first code refers to the "elsarticle-num.bst" in https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle (link found in [latex instructions - elsevier](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions))

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is working except for the spacing between items, which is too tight.

A solution is to add

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{1ex} % or whatever space you want
```

to the settings.

Comment: Re space, `em` is relevant to horizontal space; `ex` should be used for vertical.

Comment: Indeed, I fixed it!